# How to Jump from one save point to another save point of Session

Tags: javascript, .net, session

Hi I have a different situation and asking here for help.

I have a web site in which we will have articles with many number of pages. The server side technology used is .NET.

For example If I consider a article...It will have 50 pages and each will have Unique ID. And when I open a Article one session will be created. If I want to jump from page one to any other page I cannot jump directly because architecture of the server is designed to avoid jump to the any page if the previous page is not viewed. So If i want to jump to the 11th page I should have viewed the 10th page.

Here my Question is How can I jump over Pages without following that rule, Cause we are suffering from clicking next button. Is this possible? if yes, How? Here I am including in much detail

1. When I open any article from the site one session will be created for that Article.
2. As I said earlier an Article contains many number of pages with Unique ID.
3. In every page there will be a checkbox, it will be checked at the server if the page is viewed. Like visited link in html.
4. If I have viewed 30 pages and I have closed the browser and opened the same article.. Again I need to come from 1st page.. I cannot jump directly to the 31st page...
5. In server as per my knowledge one function handling this like, If client requests 31st page that will check whether 30th page is viewed or not.. In this case it will return false as that previous session was already expired and the current is new..

Comment: There is no way to answer this if we don't know how this user interface process (UIP) is implemented. Can you also elaborate more on what exactly you want to accomplish here. This is not clear to me.

Comment: @MartijnB Please have a look at the updated Question.

Comment: Ok. I still not understand why you have this feature but want to get around it? If you implemented the feature properly there shouldn't be away to circumvent it. If you want to get around if purely for development purposes then disable it while your debugging.

Comment: @MartijnB I did not implement this at server side and Can't I do this by creating client side sessions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it all correctly then the simple answer is no but depends on the implementation of the functionality which checks you where on the previous page of the page you want to visit.

So if you don't know how this works you will need to do some reverse engineering by watching what goes over the line (http headers, cookies, querystrings, post data, etc) and hope you can get a sense of what's going on. Tools like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [burp suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) can help you with that.

Now like I said before if it's implemented well you can't circumvent it by doing some tricks. You then have one solution left and that would be to automate the requests you normally make by going to one page to the next.

So for example if you want to visit the 31st page, your custom app would be making the request of the first page, the second and so fort. This will fill the session with the proper flags so that when you visit the 31st one page the validation succeeds.

It's still not clear why you want to do this. It looks like your not in charge of the server side and you want to circumvent the checks of the website. Now before you're putting things through be sure to know what you are doing. Reverse engineering could be a long long way. And the end of the day it's just a hacky solution.

Comment: @MartijinB Thanks for response.. How can I view the data being posted to server?